# iFrame element on top of the parrent

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, modal-dialog

Is it possible to place inner iframe element, like DIV, on top of the whole page including parent page?

I have a modal element showing up on button click. Problem is, interactive elements from parent page can still be interacted with when the full screen div is open.

Example:

```
<body>
 <button> //button still can be interact with and is not dimmed even when modal is open
 <iframe>
   <button onclick="openModal();">
   <div id="modal"></div> //full screen modal with background dimmed
   <script></script> //javascript to open the div on click
 </iframe>
</body>
```

I tried to use css z-index, didn't work, I can only imagine it only works within the iframe and does not interact with parent page.

What I'm trying to get is when modal is open the res of the page can't be interacted with and button on parent page stay dimmed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp Check this out

Comment: You can not “break out of” an iframe with any elements that are part of the document displayed inside it. You would have to make your iframe as big as the whole main document here, if you wanted any overlay from _within_ the iframe to cover everything.

Comment: @user12137152 that only show divs not iframe, but thanks.

Comment: I think `window.parent` , css `overflow` might help.

Comment: @user12137152 i will try that approach